# Show identical answers from query

Tags: sql, group-by, stack

Hellow guys i have a question it is posible to show and group same answers from a query?

here is the sample of the table i am working on:

Table

```
ID-----Q1-----Q2-----Q3-----Q4-----Q5-----Q6-----Q7-----Q8-----Q9-----Q10
1      Y      N      Y      N      M      N      M      M      M      Y
```

What i want to do is this:

```
Y = Q1, Q3, Q10
N = Q2, Q4
M = Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9
```

it is possible to display the name of the column in my example?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong.  What you need is a Questions table, not a table with Questions columns.

```
Questions Table
------------------
QuestionID     PK
Question       Text


Answers Table
-----------------
AnswerID       PK
QuestionID     FK
UserID         FK
Answer         Text
```

Comment: Agreed. As a general rule, if you are numbering fields within a database, it should probably be a table of it's own.